# How can I generate different names for input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Mav.png)
I am working on a HTML form where I am forced to use jQuery so that the user can add rows to the table as much as he wants. The problem is with the name of the inputs fields.

This is my function. The value of the `k` in the first text field shows just `k` not a number!

```js
var k = 0;

function myfunction(x) { //x refers to onclick($(this)) 
  alert(k);
  k++;
  var row = x.closest("tr");
  $("<tr><td></td> <td><input name=k value=k style='display:block; ;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%; border:none;');/> </td> </tr>").insertAfter(row);

  $("#myform").on("click", "TheSelectorForTheIcon", function() {
    var row = x.closest("tr");
    $("<tr>…</tr>").insertAfter(row);
  })
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding some "style" in each row, why don't you add a class to each input and some css to this class if they are the same ? And you add "k" as a string, not the var k :/

Comment: because I have  inputs  of radio type and it is effected by this , I didn't know how to except it :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the value of the `k` variable in to the HTML string. Also note that some parts of the HTML string are not necessary, such as the closing parenthesis and extra apostrophe. Try this:

```js
function myfunction($x) {
  k++;
  var $row = $x.closest("tr");
  $('<tr><td></td><td><input name="' + k + '" value="' + k + '" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: none;" /></td> </tr>').insertAfter($row);

  $("#myform").on("click", "TheSelectorForTheIcon", function() {
    var $row = $x.closest("tr");
    $("<tr>…</tr>").insertAfter($row);
  })
}
```

However the simple answer to your question about generating dynamic field names is: don't. Give the inputs the same name and deal with their values as an array on the server side.

Comment: you mean in php ?

Comment: Yes, PHP would work if that's the server side language you have access to. I can't really debug why the icon click event isn't working for you with the information you've provided. I would suggest using a single delegated event handler instead of adding one each time this function is executed, though